# How to run Laravel Queue without using artisan or shell?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

I tried `php artisan queue:work`, its runs great, the website no freezing, but how to run programatically via Controller? i run `Artisan:call('queue:work')` but its freezing (waiting the queue to finish) and end up gateway timeout, but the queue run successfully though.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Queues allow you to defer the processing of a time-consuming task, such as sending an email, until a later time.

So executing the queue worker from controller actually negate the purpose of the queues. Explain your exact use case in question to provide more details.

Comment: using Laravel 5.5 here.. I'm trying to log job( readable form of what is saved in jobs table may be ) info **before** it is deleted when run from artisan( have used shouldQueue to make email jobs ). For that I planned executing the job queue from a controller.. I might be wrong, is there a way to log each job in database. I failed logging from the queue class methods. I might be wrong, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller function

```
use Symphony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException;

try {

 $process = new Process(your artisan command,
               null,
               your environment,
               [],
               timeout(ex: 60000),[]);

 $process->run();

} catch (ProcessTimedOutException $e) {

 // you can show some flash message

 // OR
 return Response::json(['message' => 'some message'], 'desire response code');

}
```

In your case, you need to do some font-end hack, run this controller function as ajax and make some loading. And stop the loading after your desire time is pass.

This is not a best approach, you should not run `queue` process from controller, you should let your server to do this process by using `supervisor, etc…` 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration